# Rails: link_to with path with automatic scope parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing web app where each organization (group) has own subdomain (as namespace). Unfortunately it's not working on heroku.

So I'm trying to change whole concept from `group_name.myapp.com/resources` to `myapp.com/group_name/resources`.

Here's my route file now

```
  scope ':group' do
    resources :clients
    resources :carriers
    resources :transport_orders
  end
```

Before change my links worked well, because paths were automatically pointing to subdomain. Now every `link_to` needs to have specified *:group* parameter.

How to automatically specify `:group` parameter for links or have I to do it manually?